# SQL Result of SELECT more than one row

Tags: sql, loops, select, db2, distinct

I have code similar to what is shown below and I keep getting the error - Result of SELECT more than one row

```
UPDATE myDatabaseOne.myTableOne t1
SET firstFieldToCopy = (SELECT DISTINCT alternateField 
                        FROM myDatabaseTwo.myTableTwo t2
                        WHERE t1.firstFieldToCopy = t2.alternateField 
                          AND t2.Field <> t2.Field2);
```

How do I get it to loop for each value in t1?

Comment: Use php to get values from ur databases and do anything you want to do

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  A loop within an update doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the sub query returns multiple values for (some of) the record(s) updated. You should change it so it is guaranteed only to return a single value, e.g. add TOP 1 in the select (although that does make it more or less pick a value at random)

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it will not always be a single value.

I am comparing a column in one table with a column in a different table.
The key for both records must be the same.  If the values that are compared are different from one another, then that value will be updated in the original table in a different column.

Comment: I just re-read your query and I'm a little confused what you want to do. It looks like you want to update field myTableOne.firstFieldToCopy with myTableTwo.alternateField, and you're looking for the record in myTableTwo based on myTableOne.firstFieldToCopy = myTableTwo.alternateField. Wouldn't that mean you're always copying the value myTableOne already has?

Comment: Maybe you can post some sample data (doesn't have to be much) of myTableOne and myTableTwo and explain what the query would do to the sample data?

Comment: I need to add additional criteria to make the record further unique